# Building a Sites Application: Using Sites and Spreadsheets Together

Tags: web-applications, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-sites

My question relates to this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/building-sites-app-part1) 
Can this script work if visitors are not logged into a Google account?
I didn't get a reply from Google. The issue isn't about the real functionality of the script I am just trying to understand what I can do with Google sites. I am not trying to capture the user name with anonymous user. My problem with the script is that it only seems to work with Chrome.

Comment: My question is about the script available in this tutorial. Please test that script before your reply.

Comment: If you think it is possible to make the same script works for anon users (with user name text box) on any browsers then post it and that will make you better than the tutorial.

Comment: Also this will have to be a customized domain because I think it could impact on other browsers.

Comment: Perhaps this will help you answering me?https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=513

Answer (score 0):

**Editted whole answer 1st May 2014:**
According to my tests, the first anonymous user's times will be entered but the UserID column is blank. A second anonymous user entering data results in the first anonymous user's data being changed. This seems to be due to lines 333 and 361 in the script.

The solution I think would be to add a textbox to the app for a user to enter a name, then adapt the script to process that input and enter it in the UserID column.

Zig's answer below made me realise that

1. The link I gave on sharing sites link did not go to the most relevant page. [This is the more relevant page.](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/98182?hl=en&ref_topic=4565694)
2. For this script it turns out that you don't need to share the spreadsheet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think I have shared to everybody. Could you test this particular script?

Comment: First all thanks for undertaking some testing. What you say makes a lot of sense but is still incomplete. I am quite new to the product. I have done some testing but I am not familiar with the product and the language so I don't want to mislead people. I have asked Google a question in regard to the limitation of the product but they advised me to come on here. May I ask what browsers (IE, Chrome or Firefox) did you use for your testing? I tend to agree with your reply but only with chrome.

Comment: Google will never answer such a question, because they dont have the resources to provide free coding assistance, and there is no need for them to get involved since you can just try it yourself like the guy who answered here. Furthermore if you read the script, it calls Session.getActiveUser().getUserLoginId() and thus that would never work (returns null then casted to empty string).

Comment: this script is provided by google as an example. I am not asking for free coding assistance.

Comment: Yes you are asking for coding assistance with your modification of script behavior. Plus all you have asked is easy to try yourself like the one who answered did. In any case its a complete working sample thus google will not give you free consulting.

Comment: I am not asking for coding assistance. I said if you think that it is possible to make the same script work with any major browsers and with anon visitors then post it. As far as I am concern, the script in this tutorial only works with Chrome and Logged in users. A very important detail.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the script. The other answers are not right suggesting that you must share the sheet and/or script. Its neither. Publish the site as public, publish the script to run as owner with anonymous access. Thats all there is.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't depend on the script. I am providing a script in my question and my question is related to this script.

Comment: Seeing the new link to the sample, Ive added some comments to the other answer, but this answer still applies. once you have anon access, do as the other answer says and add a box to type the user. Of course there would be no security and anyone could enter anything including a cowoker's name

Comment: I believe it is more complicated than that. It also depends on the browser. of course I have never expected the login name to be captured when the visitor is anon.

Comment: No it does not depend on the browser as long as you use a browser officially supported by the google apps plattform (google it, its the last 2 versions of the 4 major browsers). Its NOT more complicated than my answer otherwise post specifics. Its a very easy task to look at the script code and realize how it works (i did)

Comment: It is still unanswered and you still don't understand the question. I am not asking anything about my own coding. I am trying to understand the limit of the product. As per my experience the script doesn't  work on my IE 11. Prove me wrong then!

Comment: I wont invest any more time on this. See my apps-script rank in s.o.

Comment: Answering this question requires time indeed, it more than advising to share the site..this was already in the tutorial.

Comment: thats not what was adviced, it involves adding an edit box so the anonymous user can enter its email. Also, the API does work in IE, but you are maybe trying it from a gmail account and you cant get a users email unless you are on a GAB domain account, not free. to get any email account you would need to pubish the script to run as the user, and that would break other things. also involves changing the site's permissions. To avoid sites issues you can just run the script directly from its webapp url, as old IE versions have trouble iframing the webapp in sites.

Comment: Does this work on your IE? Including the iframe? it doesn't work on my machine and I am using IE 11 http://dev.digital-consolidation.co.uk/

Comment: Luckily Ive never had to ever use IE again nor do I plan to let it run on my devices ever again. But yes, under some browsers getActiveUser fails when the script is embedded in a site. Just dont embed it.

Comment: Are you saying that if I don't use getActiveUSer then the EMBEDED Script will work even in IE?

Comment: I don't really believe it because the embeded frame doesn't even load. Prove it!

Comment: Ok enough with you. I really wont touch this anymore. If you actually read my answer it mentions the iframing issue and provides a workarround.

Comment: Provide a workaround? It is not what I am looking for. Again I said several time that my question is related to the limits of the product not an actual coding need. The tutorial (which is embedded) only works if a visitor is logged into a google account and uses Chrome. That makes googles sites web application only good for "intra net" like apps so companies will stick with the good old Microsoft office which is more expensive but properly supported.

Comment: BTW for your information the easiest workaround would be to use Google form with script which do the same thing and it does work embedded with IE. As far as as my concern, I am happy to not use GAB professionally as I can imagine the face of my client when the apps doesn't work on IE.